# How to get fields of DataGrid cell

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

In my WPF app, i have a Window(all code) that contains DataGrid. There's my DataGrid binding:

```
using (var db = new CompanyEntities())
{
    var stocks = db.Stock;
    var query = from s in stocks
                select new { s.Id_Product, s.Quantity };
    dataGrid.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
}
```

I want to read cell that is selected in DataGrid. I tried to read it using DataGrid.SelectedItem, but to get to the item i have to cast it to some type. I can't use Stock class, because my DataGrid cells contains 2 out of 3 fields of Stock. So i made another class to represent DataGrid cell:

```
    class TableItem
    {
        public int Id_Product;
        public int? Quantity;
    }
```

And tried to cast it like this:

```
TableItem x = (TableItem)dataGrid.SelectedItem;
```

But i get InvalidCastException from type:

> '<>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.Int32,System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]]'

to my TableItem type.

So how should i get selected cell of my dataGrid?

**My walkaround:**

In my CompanyEntites constructor i set:

```
 this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

And now i can cast `Stock s = (Stock)dataGrid.SelectedItem;`without an exception, before switching ProxyCreation off, my SelectedItem was DynamicProxy.Stock~~ type.

Comment: Add breakpoint, use watch window. See what type `dataGrid.SelectedItem` actually is. Cast it to that.

Comment: It's  value is { Id_Product = 3, Quantity = 10 }
and type: <Anonymous Type>

Comment: Oops, should've seen that.

Answer (score 2):

Change your query like so:

```
var query = from s in stocks
            select new TableItem { Id_Product = s.Id_Product, Quantity = s.Quantity };
```

And then cast `SelectedItem` to `TableItem`, now that it actually IS one. In C#, just because it looks like another class, doesn't mean it *is* that other class.

Alternatively, don't write a new class just because you happen not to need one property of the existing class. Just use the existing class:

```
//  Don't think you need to call ToList() here
dataGrid.ItemsSource = db.Stock;
```

...and cast `SelectedItem` to whatever that is.

> my DataGrid cells contains 2 out of 3 fields of Stock:

So what? Is the problem that you get an extra column? Define the columns explicitly, just the ones you need.

Comment: I didn't want to write new class in every table, so i defined columns manualy. But then SelectedItem type was member of DynamicProxies. So in my entity context i set Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false. And now SelectedItem type is Stock, so i can use it as i want.